# Python CMS for Etsy-like website

Tags: django, content-management-system, python-2.7, django-cms

I am a novice in Python and would like to build a website similar to Etsy (same basic functionality, different market).

Functionality:
-User (buyer/seller) profiles
-Ability to upload pictures
-Seller posting
-User-to-user messaging
-Payment platform (directly from buyer to seller)

Can someone please recommend an appropriate Python/Django CMS that would provide: (1) the functionality above and, (2) also be easy for a novice to use?

Thanks!

Comment: try asking on webmasters.stackexchange.com, not here.

Comment: I don't think a CMS is appropriate for your requirements. Check our pinax

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks, I've posted my question there as well.

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony Thanks, I will check out pinax as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a django based CMS project, which supports many 3rd party plugins. 
But you need to learn how to setup a django project first.

https://github.com/divio/django-cms